# recursive method multiplying without using operator

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LAB1201 {
    static int multi(int a, int b){
        int c = 0;
        if (b == 0) {
            c = 0;
        }

        if (b < 0) {
            c = (-multi(a, -b));
        }

        if (b > 0) {
            c = (a + multi(a, b-1));
        }

        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int aa;
        int bb;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in a integer");
        aa = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type in another integer");
        bb = scanner.nextInt();
        multi(aa,bb);
    }
}
```

I am coding 
(Write a recursive function that multiplies two numbers x and y using recursion (do not
use the multiplication operator). Your main method should prompt the user for the two
numbers, call your function, and print the result)

It allows me to type in values but I am not sure why it is not returning any values 
it returns nothing..

Comment: BTW you want to print `multi(aa,bb);`

Comment: Your code is fine, but you forgot to print the output.

Comment: You haven't _told_ it to return anything, or to print anything out.

Comment: Just type System.out.println(multi(aa,bb)) to print the returned value, but the rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to output the value.

```
System.out.println(aa + " x " + bb + " = " + multi(aa,bb));
```

Output example:

```
Type in a integer
4
Type in another integer
8
4 x 8 = 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You just forgot to print the result returned by method `static int multi(int a, int b)`. You can find working code [here](http://ideone.com/tsopif)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a printing statement. Here is the code, please have a look.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class so {
static int multi(int a, int b){
    int c = 0;
    if(b<0){
        return c=(-multi(a, -b));
    }
    if(b>0){
        return c=(a+multi(a, b-1));
    }
    return c;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
    int aa;
    int bb;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in a integer");
    aa = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type in another integer");
    bb = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println(multi(aa,bb));
}
```